# Как сократить регулярное выражение

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Представим очень большую регулярку, которая в одной строке забирает все между тегами, например:

```
'>значение<'
```

Для этого напишем что-то вроде:

```
>([^<]+)
```

Подобных одинаковых абсолютно кусков выражения может быть много.

Можно ли заключить их в группу типа:

```
(?'value'[^<]+)
```

и использовать в другом куске этого же выражения по типу `>(value)`?

Comment: То есть найти совпадение в одном месте РВ, а потом проверить в другом месте того же РВ на равенство?

Comment: @Vesper, то есть заключить subexpression в именованную группу и использовать его имя в другом месте этого же выражения, чтоб не плодить кучу одинаковых букв.

Comment: Проще использовать `string.Format()` для "сложения" регулярного выражения. Нет в .NET `\g<n>` и рекурсии, как в PCRE.

Comment: @stribizhev, понял Вас, спасибо

Comment: Т.е. скажем, есть регексп для "email-address", он здоровый, и нужно, чтобы построенный регексп его использовал в двух разных местах, а-ля "blabla ("email-address part") foo ("email-address part") boo"? Проще собирать регексп как строку в таком раскладе. Т.е. есть у тебя строка с регекспом `String email_address`, и ты её состыковываешь в необходимый регексп, хоть сколько раз добавляй.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Так как в в .NET нет `\g<n>` и рекурсии, как в PCRE, невозможно внутри регулярного выражения использовать ссылку на часть регулярного выражения.

Для этого проще использовать `string.Format()`:

```
var something = "[^<]*";
var regex = new Regex(string.Format(">{0}<.*?>{0}<", something));
```

Пример использования строковой интерполяции:

```
var block = "[^<]*";
var regex = new Regex($@">{block}<.*?>{block}<");
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `string.Format(">{0}<.*?>{1}<", something, something)` - что за??? Это же не printf. `string.Format(">{0}<.*?>{0}<", something)` надо!